# linking wxWidgets cross-compiled program gives "undefined reference to `wxFrameNameStr'"

Tags: g++, wxwidgets, mingw32, unsatisfiedlinkerror, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build and link a wxWidgets program for MS Windows using a cross-compiler on Linux. Because my program uses wxMediaCtrl, and because the Fedora install of the cross-compiler does not include wxMediaCtrl (why?), I have had to build wx itself. I can compile my program but when I try to link it I get all these link errors like "undefined reference to `wxFrameNameStr".

The wx website is down and has been for some time, so I may be doing something wrong that is documented there. But I cannot work out what to do.

I configured wx with:

./configure --prefix=/home/martin/wx/a --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --disable-shared --disable-debug     --disable-threads --disable-monolithic --enable-unicode     --without-libjpeg --without-libpng --without-zlib    --without-libtiff --without-expat --without-regex --enable-mediactrl --enable-sound

I have been trying to build my program like (among several varations):

i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o qqq `/home/martin/wx/a/bin/wx-config --cppflags  --ld --libs media,std` qqqApp.cpp qqq.cpp

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

OK, think I found the answer: the loader options have to come after the file names.

Comment: Yes, *static* libraries must always come after the objects (or other libraries) referencing them when using the traditional Unix linkers.